# Only run test when useEffect in Provider is done

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, use-effect

I have a I18n provider that's constructed like this:

```
export function LanguageProvider({ children }) {
  const lng = getLanguageFromPathname() 
  const [langIsLoaded, setLangIsLoaded] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadI18n = async () => {
      await i18next.use(initReactI18next).init({
        resources: {
          source: sourceLanguage,
          en: enLanguage,
          ach: achLanguage,
        },
        lng,
        fallbackLng: 'source',
      })
      setLangIsLoaded(true)
    }
    loadI18n()
  }, [lng])
  if (!langIsLoaded) {
    return null
  }
  return <React.Fragment key={lng}>{children}</React.Fragment>
}
```

In my Jest tests I want to access the `I18next` object that's initialized inside the `useEffect`, which isn't ready on first render.

How do I run the tests only when the above mentioned object is initialized?

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to watch for variable changes in brackets in 
useEffect(() => {},[variable])

export function LanguageLoader({ children }) {
  const lng = getLanguageFromPathname() 
  const [langIsLoaded, setLangIsLoaded] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadI18n = async () => {
      await i18next.use(initReactI18next).init({
        resources: {
          source: sourceLanguage,
          en: enLanguage,
          sv: svLanguage,
        },
        lng,
        fallbackLng: 'source',
      })
      setLangIsLoaded(true)
    }
    loadI18n()
  })
  if (!langIsLoaded) {
    return null
  },[i18next]
  return <React.Fragment key={lng}>{children}</React.Fragment>
}
```

Comment: That's true, but unfortunately adding `[lng]` to `useEffect` isn't enough to solve my issue.